# YouTube crashes the entire computer and it will not boot up again

Tags: crash, youtube, xfce4, debian-buster

I was watching YouTube when the computer froze. I turned it on, and it crashed while watching YouTube again.

So I left it off overnight. In the morning it did not boot and had a blank screen, not even [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test).

it’s a computer running [Debian 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_10_(Buster)) (Buster) and [Xfce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce) 4.

Comment: Does the power LED turn on and stay on? Can you see/hear the fans spin?

Comment: Yes the Power LED turns on and stays on and I can hear the fans spin.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

I restarted the router and the computer booted up again.

Comment: If it is an intermittent problem, it may be coincidental.